# Numerically normalize within a function

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function

I'm trying to (elegantly) normalize a function numerically, depending on the parameters that are passed into it.  The example below gives a Gaussian that tries to normalize within the function but fails.

I know I could do this with a couple extra lines of code, or for this example normalize analytically; I'm specifically asking about *creating a numerically normalized anonymous function*:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,10000);
my_gauss = @(w) exp(-1/(2*w^2) * x.^2) / trapz((x(2)-x(1))*my_gauss(w));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between an elegant solution and a solution that is efficient, clear, and correct. MATLAB has no built-in method that normalizes an array.

Based on the example that you have provided, you are trying to do too much with your anonymous function, and as a result it's not actually that general (can't deal with non-uniform sampling, etc).

I think you'd be better off creating two anonymous functions: one to perform the normalization, and the other to compute the gaussian:

```
x = linspace(-10, 10, 10000);

normalize = @(x, g)g ./ trapz(x, g);
gaussian = @(x, w)exp(-1 / (2 * w^2) * x.^2);

normalized_gaussian = normalize(x, gaussian(x, 10));

disp(trapz(x, normalized_gaussian))

    1

% Or if you want to provide a single anonymous function
ngaussian = @(x, w)normalize(x, gaussian(w));
```

This is much more explicit and breaks out the functionality into more logical units that can be better understood and tested. Additionally, it can handle functions evaluated at random intervals.

Comment: I would be surprised if this were too much for a single function, but you may be right.  Also, trapz is implemented fine in my solution.  Nevertheless, pretty good solution!

Comment: Yea so the real reason that this can't be done in MATLAB is that you can't really have recursion within an anonymous function.

Comment: Oh I see what you did with trapz, that's also not super general though because if you do it the way that I did (with x, and g as inputs) this allows for non-uniform samples in x whereas yours assumes uniform samples (usually a safe bet, but not always :))